# How to invert a `HashMap<String, MyEnum>`? (Error: "`FromIterator` not implemented for [pair]")

Tags: rust

I'm trying to invert a `HashMap<String, MyEnum>` in Rust, and getting an error:

- [Rust Playground instance](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1553c5430df98cbe9d0e2d45d8934a68)

**Code:**

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

// Directive added because of this answer, which eliminated a couple of errors:
// https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/22756#issuecomment-75715762
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
enum MyEnum {
    Value1,
    Value2,
}

static MYMAP: HashMap<String, MyEnum> = HashMap::from([
    (String::from("value1"), MyEnum::Value1),
    (String::from("value1"), MyEnum::Value1),
]);

static MYMAP_INVERTED: HashMap<MyEnum, String> = HashMap::from([
    MYMAP.iter().map(|(k, v)| (v, k)).collect()
]);
```

**Error:**

```
error[E0277]: a value of type `(_, _)` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `(&MyEnum, &String)`
    --> src/main.rs:15:39
     |
15   |     MYMAP.iter().map(|(k, v)| (v, k)).collect()
     |                                       ^^^^^^^ value of type `(_, _)` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=(&MyEnum, &String)>`
     |
     = help: the trait `FromIterator<(&MyEnum, &String)>` is not implemented for `(_, _)`
note: required by a bound in `collect`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

**How would you implement `FromIterator` for a pair?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is ok, your types are wrong. Either you have references:

```rust
let my_map_inverted: HashMap<&MyEnum, &String> = my_map.iter()
    .map(|(k, v)| (v, k)).collect();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ea785bdcf643fda080aa568483e6ed49)

Or you `Clone` the keys and values:

```rust
let my_map_inverted: HashMap<MyEnum, String> = my_map.iter()
    .map(|(k, v)| (v.clone(), k.clone())).collect();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=529055f715a6a756318f84dd4c2f1761)

Then you have some other problems, like some calls cannot be used in static context, you can use [`once_cell`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/index.html) for that:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use once_cell::sync::Lazy; // 1.10.0;

// Directive added because of this answer, which eliminated a couple of errors:
// https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/22756#issuecomment-75715762
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Hash, Clone)]
enum MyEnum {
    Value1,
    Value2,
}

static MYMAP: Lazy<HashMap<String, MyEnum>> = Lazy::new(
    || HashMap::from_iter([
        (String::from("value1"), MyEnum::Value1),
        (String::from("value1"), MyEnum::Value1),
]));

static MYMAP_INVERTED: Lazy<HashMap<MyEnum, String>> = Lazy::new(
    || HashMap::from_iter(MYMAP.iter().map(|(k, v)| (v.clone(), k.clone()))
));
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e513211888520d214c0bf807da5a330c)

Comment: Is the `HashMap` going to dereference the "reference to `enum`" before calculating the key on it, or is it going to hash on the reference address?

Also, what effect does cloning an `enum` value have?

Comment: @Neil, keys are always hashed, but is not the same to hash a `&T` than a `T`. Also cloning a Enum value like that one is pretty cheap, if the enum has some other inner values could get more expensive. It will mostly depend on your needs at the time.

Answer (score 1):

To swap the keys and values, you would be better off using the [`from_iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#impl-FromIterator%3C(K%2C%20V)%3E) constructor since `from` can't take a Vec, and `collect` isn't sure what to do the way it is now. The code to do that would look like this, but you can't use methods like that in a static context, so that will require a refactor:

```rust
let MYMAP_INVERTED: HashMap<MyEnum, String> = HashMap::from_iter(
    MYMAP.iter().map(|(k, v)| (*v, k.clone()))
);
```

The `*v` and `k.clone()` are required because the `map` will return references to the data.

As for the static problem, your best bets would be either using the [`lazy_static` crate](https://docs.rs/lazy_static/1.4.0/lazy_static/) or a [`SyncLazy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/lazy/struct.SyncLazy.html) from the standard library.